# Non-printable PDF exports in SAP Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: java, crystal-reports, pdf-generation

In Crystal Reports 2011 is it possible to export a report into PDF that is non-printable or non-copyable?

I am aware of a similar feature in JasperReports as follows that enables this:
`exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);`
`exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OWNER_PASSWORD, "Pa$$w0rD");`

To allow printing, one would use
`exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, new Integer( PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING));`

Comment: Which version of CR?  Have you consulted the SDK?

Comment: @craig We will be using Crystal Server 2011. Currently we are still in the early design phase and have not got access to the SDK yet. :)